# HTML paragraph column style

Tags: php, html, css

I'm making a list and each list item has the same structure:
[image: My list item structure]

I already got the image & header in place but below the header I have a paragraph, and I don't know how to make it like it's shown in the picture (with the subject & others), like there's columns and they're at fixed locations in the list item (so they order evenly vertically).

My current paragraph is just subject: test. I don't know how to place the "other" texts.

My CSS code related to this:

```
div {
  margin: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 1000px;
}

h3 {
  font: bold 20px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

li img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

li p {
  font: 200 12px/1.5 Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

li:hover {
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

and my HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/2">
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <p>Subject: Test</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: We need to see your code for helping you.

Comment: Updated with CSS & HTML code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/4KufE/1/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/2" />
      <h3>Header</h3>
      <ul>
          <li><strong>Subject:</strong> test</li>
          <li><strong>Other:</strong> test</li>
          <li><strong>Other:</strong> test</li>
          <li><strong>Other:</strong> test</li>
          <li><strong>Other:</strong> test</li>
          <li><strong>Other:</strong> test</li>
      </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html, ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
  margin: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 1000px;
}

ul ul{
    float:right;
    width:865px;
}

li li{
    width:31%;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px 1%;
}

h3 {
  font: bold 20px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
}

li img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

li p {
  font: 200 12px/1.5 Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

li:hover {
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something like you want:

**CSS:**

```
div {
  margin: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 1000px;
}

h3 {
  font: bold 20px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;

    margin-top:-5px;
    position:relative;
}

li img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

li p {
  font: 200 12px/1.5 Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;
  margin-top:-20px;
  position:relative;

}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

li:hover {
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

and you can see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8Ydz/)